# Rotating a plane relative to a camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, 2d, unityscript

I am trying to make a child 2d plane rotate a little more (about 20 to 30 degrees) to the left or right on its y axis when a camera is looking directly at the left or right edge of the plane, so the plane never 'disappears'. I use unity 3d and Js

This is my attempt

```
var checks : float[];
var myRots : float[];
if(Mathf.Clamp(cam.transform.eulerAngles.y, checks[i]-5, checks[i] + 25) == cam.transform.eulerAngles.y)
transform.localEulerAngles.y = transform.parent.transform.rotation.y * myRots[i];
```

Here i manually input a camera degree in checks and rotate the character a certain amount with myrot. The thing is when the parent rotates, the child plane set rotations become off. What am i missing to allow the plane to behave this way no matter what the parent object's rotation is?

Comment: What is the value of `myRots[i]`? When does it get set?

Comment: myrots[i] is how much to turn the plane when the camera is at the certain checks[i] rotation.

Comment: It might help to include a mockup of the existing and intended behavior.  As written this Q is a little difficult to understand.

Comment: I made a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMfmu943-m0&feature=youtu.be